# To check whether particular string is present in text file using robotframework

Tags: string, file, find, pattern-matching, robotframework

To check whether particular string is present  in text file using robotframework

I need to match the pattern "Status:true" in text file using robotframework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the content of the file in a string and then check for the string presence in the string:

```
${my_string}    Get File    C:/path/to/my_file.txt
Should Contain    ${my_string}    Status:true
```

Comment: @Pritykumari if this works for you, please accept the answer.